# Sort files and folders in the same way in Windows Explorer - sorted by names

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sorting

I just want to **see files and folders** (sorted/grouped by their name) in a list that does **NOT separate files and folders**.

I also don't want to order by `date modified` like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/204016/windows-explorer-sorts-files-and-folders-separately).

I already tried several solutions. But unfortunaletly non worked. And I don't want to use grouped by that splits it up into A-G... and so on.

```
Antelope[dir]
Antelope.txt
Badger[dir]
Badger.txt
....
Zebra[dir]
Zebra.doc
```

Questions that also didn't help me out:

- [Sort files and folders together by name (not by type)?](https://superuser.com/questions/774180/sort-files-and-folders-together-by-name-not-by-type)
- [Sorting folders in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/834036/sorting-folders-in-windows-explorer)
- [Show Files and Folders Sorted by name NOT Folders First then Files](https://superuser.com/questions/416059/show-files-and-folders-sorted-by-name-not-folders-first-then-files)

Comment: Like XP would do ..... I despise WinX and it's 'sorting'.

Comment: [Windows 7, any way to sort folders and files all mixed together?](http://superuser.com/q/329127)

Comment: Thanks David, indeed with that new explorer there it works. But third party is always the last way to solve things. Anyway thanks. Strange that noone is writing a hack on the official explorer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**xplorer²** was able to solve this issue. Anyway I'm still interested in doing this in the Windows explorer.

Just wrote a German Tutorial about this and xplorer² (http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/03/08/windows-explorer-sortierung-f%C3%BCr-ordner-und-dateien-mit-xplorer%C2%B2/). It should be easy to understand also for non-Germans. ;)